# Does iOS still runs 32 bit app and allows same to be uploaded on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-simulator

I am currently developing an app which is using a 32 bit 3rd party library, so my app fails to  compile for 64 bit architectures (x86_64 in the iOS Simulator and arm64 for device), receiving an **"undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"** error.  The app compiles and run when i select simulators other the 64bit.

Does Apple still allows us to upload 32 bit apps to the App Store, and will my app work on 64bit iOS devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All currently shipping 64bit iOS devices support running 32bit applications.  You should be able to run a 32bit app in a 64bit simulated device as well as a real 64bit device.

Comment: But when i choose the 64bit simulated device the compiler gives error saying "undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" in 3rd party library which i m using but the same works when i choose other simulators.

Comment: You seem to be building for 64bit.  I suspect that you may have your architecture set to "match device" or similar (I forget the exact wording, sorry).  Try setting valid architectures to "32bit"

Comment: i can't find anything as you mentioned in my build settings. if you can guide me how i can make those settings will be great help.